# How to latebind COM event without interface

Tags: c#, vb6, .net-3.5, late-binding, oleview

I need to late bind to a 3rd party VB6 COM object in a 3.5 C# application (to avoid version dependencies that we currently have). The dll that was provided is not consumable in most non-latebound ways due to some bug that causes errors when we try to consume it normally. Currently, we are using a custom VB6 wrapper that makes things VERY version specific, however I have found that I can use late-binding to access properties and methods. Now, I am trying to late-bind to events, however everything I have read says that I need to inherit from the COM wrapper's interface to create the event sinks that are needed. [Here is one such article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcook/archive/2012/05/09/9023741.aspx).

So, my question is whether it is possible to perform late-bound event handling without having any reference to the dll at compile time?

**UPDATE**

Here are the errors I have with the VB6 wrapper (Which is still being actively updated).

- In OleViewer, I get

> Could not decompile selected item Error loading type library/DLL.
>   TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY ($80029C4A)

- In Visual Studio I get:

> Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference
>   "3rdPartyDLL". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Comment: I'm curious: what are the errors that you see when you try to use your VB6 object in early-bound ways? I've written many VB6 COM components and have never had any issues with using any of them in any other environments (as long as the client supported COM). Why would you even care about versioning for a VB6 component - is it sill actively developed by its author?

Comment: @xxbbcc It is still actively being developed and I updated to show the errors

Comment: @WhozCraig: VB6 events are always IDispatch based only.

Comment: It's a pity the third party can't help you avoid the versioning problems by using binary compatibility.  But if they're a third party, I guess you can complain but you may just have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://marc.info/?l=ms-dcom&m=103440617319007&w=2):

> I found that the problem is caused when the IDL contains an importlib
>   to another project's .tlb typelib.
>
> This seems to create a dependency between one dll and the other.
>
> If dependant dll is missing OLEView refuses to display the dependent
>   dll, which also manifests itself by not allowing #import from C++
>   code.

Therefore I would look carefully at the COM dependencies of the DLL in question and make sure they are all registered as well.

It also goes on to add:

> ...because both dlls are co-dependent,
>   components from each interact (via interface declarations on method
>   signatures) and use `#import` from each others typelib.
>
> Therefore, unless both target dlls are present, neither can be
>   rebuilt. As you can imagine, this causes a terrible problem when you
>   try to completely rebuild the project's from scratch.
>
> I've experimented with separating the interface definitions into
>   smaller IDL files...

---

**Edit:** here's a recent example of this problem coming about (I believe). I had a C# library exported to COM. Modifications to that library were made which changed the interface of several classes, but the library GUID was not changed. Also [see here about risks of `AutoDual`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714430/why-should-i-not-use-autodual) which was in use.

Here's the odd part - the VB6 DLL was rebuilt referencing the modified C# DLL. *It compiled fine*. no errors. But its typelib was corrupt - OleView couldn't open it, failing with `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY`. Changing the C# DLL GUID was necessary to get the VB6 DLL recompiled successfully.

Clearly a pitfall of VB6 / C# interop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably caused by the platform you are using. I just had a similar problem yesterday. Make sure that you are setting your project platform to **x86** / **x64** when you are late binding a x86/x64 COM type library.

The same applies to `oleview`. Use the x86/x64 version to view x86/x64 type libraries. (Possibly you need to install the x64 Windows SDK if you are on an x64 system to get the correct executeable).