# Is there a default default property?

Tags: c#, com-interop, idl

I'm exporting a C# class to VB6 through COM interop. **It seems to have a default COM property without me ever having set one!**

The C# class looks like:

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
class Foo
{
     public int I { get; set; }
     public bool B { get; set; }
     public int Value { get; set; }  // <--- the culprit
     public string S { get; set; }
}
```

<sub>(I know [why should I not use autodual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714430/why-should-i-not-use-autodual) - please overlook that, its useful for this stage of development)</sub>

The property `Value` is behaving as the default in VB6. It is shown this way in object browser. But notice that I have not set a `DispId` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to indicate the default.

Also, in OLEView you can see that in the `IDL` of the `TLB` for the assembly the Value property has [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/id) `[id(00000000), propget]`. This [is equivalent to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/dispid-constants) `DISPID_VALUE`. So, for some reason the compiler or TLBEXP or something is explicitly making `Value` into the default.

Why is this happening? I actually *don't want* a default property and its existence was masking a coding mistake which "just worked", basically by accident.

Comment: In VB6 a lot of things just work by accident.

Comment: Tlbexp.exe does that.  View the type library with oleview.exe, File > View TypeLib.  [dispid] auto-generation is not documented, but this is not horribly insensible.  Use the [DispId] attribute to override.

Comment: Are you sure the property was not configured using the "Procedure Attributes" dialog box?

Comment: @SimonMourier isn't that for VB6 code, not for C# code? Is there such a thing in VS2015 also?

Comment: @HansPassant I guess does it look for a property named "Value" then?

Comment: It does not have anything else to look for, so yes.  Could be interesting if you give the class an indexer btw.

Comment: Oops I got that the other way around.

Comment: @SimonMourier no worries, thanks!